# Why do these modules have to be included in the correct order for CanCanCan to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancan, cancancan

I have the following code for being able to render an XML document without it being part of a request:

```
class ExportMetadataService
  # Inheriting avoids NoMethodError: undefined method `abstract?' for Object:Class
  class ItemOfflineTemplate < AbstractController::Base
    # Used for render_to_string
    include AbstractController::Rendering
    # Both of the following lines are required for cancan, and have to be in the correct order.
    include AbstractController::Helpers
    include CanCan::ControllerAdditions

    attr_accessor :item

    def initialize
      # No evidence of being required, but probably good practice.
      super()
      # Avoids ActionView::MissingTemplate
      lookup_context.view_paths = Rails.root.join('app', 'views')
    end

    # CanCan requires a current_user
    def current_user
      @current_user ||= User.admins.first
    end
  end
end
```

The code for rendering the XML is the following:

```
item = Item.first
template = ExportMetadataService::ItemOfflineTemplate.new
template.item = item
template.render_to_string :template => "items/show.imp.xml"
```

and the template starts with

```
-if can? :manage, @item
```

If I run the code as shown above, it works fine. However, if I change the order of the controllers, such that `include CanCan::ControllerAdditions` happens before `include AbstractController::Helpers`, it gives the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `can?' for #<#<Class:0x007fa2871821e0>:0x007fa28718bab0>
from /Users/agrimm/rails/nabu/app/views/items/show.imp.xml.haml:1:in `_app_views_items_show_imp_xml_haml__3049376767338038218_70168013983060'
```

It can't be that `CanCan::ControllerAdditions` overrides a method in `AbstractController::Helpers`, because it's a NoMethodError, rather than `AbstractController::Helpers` providing an implementation that isn't desired.

I'm using Rails 3.2, and CanCanCan 1.13.1.